# LARAVEL - set multiple rule on gate

Tags: laravel

So i wanna return id_level 1,2, and 3 that able to access view-inv but turns out it just the first one `return $user->id_level === 1;` that work, any possible way to do this?

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('view-inv', function($user){
        return $user->id_level === 1;
        return $user->id_level === 2;
        return $user->id_level === 3;
    });
}
```

my controller

```
 public function index()
{
    if (Gate::allows('view-inv')) {
        $inventaris = Inventaris::all();
        return view('index', compact('inventaris'));
    }elseif (Gate::denies('view-inv')) {
        return view('/home');
    } else {
        return view('/home');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't return more than once from function, so basically you can check if $user->id_level is "in array" with permission

```
    Gate::define('view-inv', function($user){
    return in_array($user->id_level, [1, 2, 3]);
});
```

you can define the array as constant, or just hardcode it as in example

function says, if id_level has value is the equal with some value in array return true, otherwise return false